# am trying to extracht hash tags using the neattext function but i keep getting this error. TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, object, jupyter, typeerror

```
import neattext.functions as nfx
df['Tweets']
df['Tweets'].apply(nfx.extract_hashtags)
```

am trying to extracht hash tags using the neattext function but i keep getting this error.  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

to fix the error you can convert the text to string
eg

#### Method 1

```
df['Tweets'].apply(lambda x: nfx.extract_hashtags(str(x)))
```

#### Method 2: using astype

```
df['Tweets'].astype(str).apply(nfx.extract_hashtags))
```